# Which Hotkey generates the incode comments in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for the hotkey in eclipse which allows you to do a e.g.

```
object.someFunction(/*somedoc*/someArgument);
```

e.g. the `/*somedoc*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text you want to comment, and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Edit: The above is my default binding to the command *Add Block Comment*. You can go in the *Window* menu, then select *Preferences*. In this dialog, go in General -> Editors -> Keys, and find the command *Add Block Comment*. You should be able to find the key binding on your Eclipse installation, and change it to your liking.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + / is collapsing all functions of a java class for me. CTRL + SHIFT + * is uncollapse. I have eclipse helios 3.6.2

Comment: @Toskan Good point. I've edited my answer to give details on how to change the key binding.

Comment: well... actually it is set to that and no conflicts are showing. Okay but I guess that must be my own problem.

Answer (score 2):

`Alt+Shift+J` for java doc comment. Here is [link [1](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/add-comments-and-javadocs) for possible short cut keys for different comments.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + / is collapsing all functions of a java class for me. CTRL + SHIFT + * is uncollapse. I have eclipse helios 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

If you do /** then hit enter key above a method or class it will auto-generate some documentation comments for you. This behavior is controlled windows->preferences and them something like code templates.

Comment: i believe you have to do /** before hitting enter, otherwise it sees it as a normal comment rather than a javadoc comment and it will not auto-fill the javadoc fields.

Comment: Yup, sorry need to think more before just posting.